# why does the element temporarily return to its original position?

Tags: vue.js, draggable

I use vue draggable in a vue3 project.
Every now and then, the element goes back to its original position after the drop.
I have the same problem with the examples of vue draggable:
https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/two-lists

I have the problem in every browser (Firefox, Safari, Chrome).
I have tried to change the end event without success.
What can I do so that it doesn't fall back to the original position?